# Two long visits to USA on VWP

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program

Next year 2015 I intend on travelling to Texas to spend time with my family back end of Jan for 90 days. I would return to UK (British national) beginning to mid april. Do you think it would be possible to then return to Texas around the 10th of June for another 90 day stint? The place is so vast and there is so much to see and do.

I own a property here in the UK, I could provide employers letters each time confirming my intention to return to the UK, and I wouldnt be back again after summer until mid 2016.

I really would like to do these two stints, but the most important time for me to be there is the second stay in the summer (my family are teachers and are off from work and we can have more time together).

I'd hate to go in the spring, only to be turned around at the airport in June. Do you believe an 8 or so week gap between visits is enough, along with my sufficient documentation?

I spent 90 days in texas in the summer recently and would like to make it an annual summer trip, although next year I want to fit two trips in.

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: i guess you mean with "esta". purely one opinion, no problem at all.  but, perhaps you should just get an old-fashioned visa if you're going that often? (simply phone the usa embassy/consulate in london, they'll help you right out).  get a burger for me in longview!

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that you must spend more time out of the US than in it.  So if you're staying for 90 days, then you should generally stay out for 90 days before returning...

Comment: @JoeBlow What do you mean "I guess you mean with 'esta'"?  ESTA is a system that VWP travelers have to use, but it's still the VWP.

Answer (score 3):

From the [U.S. Customs and Border Protection website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/~/about-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization-(esta)):

> When traveling to the U.S. with the approved ESTA, you may only stay for up to 90 days at a time - and there should be a reasonable amount of time between visits so that the CBP Officer does not think you are trying to live here. There is no set requirement for how long you must wait between visits.

As you can read, there is no set time limit between two visits. Admission is at Officer's own discretion.
Having said that, I *personally* believe you won't have any problem in going twice in the same year.

Last year I was admitted in the USA twice in a few months (August and October), but I stayed for much shorter periods (20 days and 7 days).